# Limit some methods to certain objects

Tags: java

I want to limit the use of some methods to some objects. I explain :)
I have some general objects, let's say `Ticket`, with the following structure:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Ticket {

    @SerializedName("@type")
    private String type;
    private String ticketToken;
    private String url;
    private String ticketUrl;
    private UnderName underName;

    @SerializedName("ticketedSeat")
    private Seat seat;

    private String ticketNumber;
    private String description;
}
```

So assuming that other objects can access it, but with different usages. For example: `Ship` object has a `Ticket` property that uses `type`, `ticketNumber` and `underName`.
But `Train` object has a `Ticket` property that uses `type`, `ticketToken` and `description`.

I was wondering if there's a feature (annotation maybe) so the developer will be able to know which fields are related to the objects or any idea how to create something like that.

I hope I have made myself clear :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what inheritance is for.

Comment: Maybe you should focus on basic programming skills, like inheritance and so on before using frameworks like Lombok...

Comment: @ThomasBöhm In this case, Lombok is simply being used to get rid of irrelevant boilerplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do

```
public class TrainTicket extends Ticket {
    //train properties
}

public class ShipTicket extends Ticket {
    //ship properties
}
```

Bonus, you could then make ticket an abstract class

Answer (score 0):

- One choice if to have different classes, with potentially a common parent/interface and each child class would define its own methods. This choice is great if it is really important to distinguish the difference with different types. In practice developpers will have to perform "instanceof" check everywhere and cast to access the data.
- On choice is to do as you do and to not even enforce anything. The key asset if the 2 childs Train & Ship share a Ticket but not the FreeTransport type. You would not put the Ticket in the parent and duplicate its definition in 2 childs. If this is repeated for many child it is a waste of time. But you'll likely want an enum or a type to recognize the type of transportation to know what you'd expect to be available. You would also do it if the system doesn't really care of the concept of Train vs Ship but actually behave only if function of what is actually present regardless of the type.